# how to send error emails to the developer in laravel 8 App

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-8

I am using laravel `"laravel/framework": "^8.75"` version.
When deployed the app turn APP_DEBUG=false but users get errors but they can not know what is wrong and me to I don't know because I tested it but my trial go through without an error.
I need to receive an email of any error exceptions that are thrown on the app in details like APP_DEBUG=true.
All the solutions I have found are of other versions whose `App\Exceptions\Handler` is having `report()` and `render()` classes yet here I have

```
public function register(){
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }
```

Comment: Any errors that would be displayed when `APP_DEBUG=true` (like it is in development) are logged to a file in the `storage/framework/logs` folder. If you need an email sent out, you'll have to code that as a custom solution, or use an external service like Rollbar or similar.

Comment: Sending Error Logs to email is not good idea. You might block your smtp/hostings to blacklist as it may recognized as spam. Isn't it easier to just look up the logs file(-s) in /storage/logs folder?

Comment: I used code solution on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60683968/laravel-7-email-exceptions-broke-after-symfony-5-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60683968/laravel-7-email-exceptions-broke-after-symfony-5-update)  in a Version 7 app emails are coming

Comment: @tokkerbaz thank you, your recommendation has helped me to find out

Comment: You can use Sentry